# Can a noun be used to describe another noun

Tags: adjectives, nouns

While reading an article I came across the following sentence:

The more successful group, in terms of their **creativity quality** of their solutions...

Is this grammatically correct? Can a noun be used to describe another noun?

Comment: A noun ***can*** be used to describe another noun - that's called a "noun adjunct" usage, as in ***a car door, the school playground***. But you can't do this with just any pair of nouns, and ***the creativity quality*** would almost never be idiomatic (but in certain contexts you might *just* get away with it if "**creativity**" were in "scare quotes").

Comment: ...as expected, there are a few written instances of [***the creativity gene***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+creativity+gene%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ_PXWgZ7iAhXiqHEKHSwlDt0QpwUIIg&biw=1398&bih=745&dpr=1.2) in Google Books. But this is somewhat "creative" use of language, in which context I'd suggest non-native speakers should probably avoid it (there are more ways to get it wrong than to get it right).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the remarks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A noun *can* act as an adjective to another. If it does so, it's called an [*attributive noun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) (or a *noun adjunct*).

However, the specific sentence in the question is ungrammatical.

> ✘ The more successful group, in terms of **their creativity quality** of their solutions . . .

The following would both be grammatical versions of the same sentence:

> ✔ The more successful group, in terms of **the creative quality** of their solutions, was . . .
>
> ✔ The more successful group, in terms of **their creative quality**, was . . .

Which one to choose would depend on what was actually being expressed. (Since it's not a complete sentence, it's not entirely clear.)

Also note that, stylistically, some people might choose to use *its* as the pronoun for a group rather than *their*.

Comment: My guess is that the writer really meant, "The more successful group, in terms of the **creativity** of their solutions..."